# Get a group note from the scope of a node within that group

Tags: scripting, node-editor

Is there a way to get to the group node from the scope of a active node with the group? Let's say I have a material with a group (G). With that group I have let's say a Noise node. How can I get to the pointer of the group (G) if I only know the pointer to the Noise node. I've tried the "Parent" property but that always return "None".

The overall issue is, that I want to add a socket to the Group Output node from within the group. But it seems as if that can only done from outside the group. If I try to add a socket to the Group Output node directly, I get a "Cannot add socket to build-in node".

Thanks for any advice on that.

Comment: Can you elaborate why you only have a node, but without its group? what is the context for that?

Comment: I use Serpens, a plugin for creating addons. So my options might be limited or not as easily accessible as if I used plain code.
The addon that I want to create start from the selected node. In the case of this issue, the node is inside a node group. The question is, how to get the pointer to the container group if I have to pointer to the selected node. I hope this makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: node.id_data should refer to the node group.

Comment: Thanks, lemon. That works.